# Filter incoming mails with too much recipents

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

I'm tired of mass forwarded messages and want to delete any future email that meets a criteria such as having more than 10 recipients in the TO: or CC: headers.

How do I set up such a filter in in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a rule/filter in Thunderbird, as far as I know...I don't have it myself, but here is a tutorial on:

> [Creating, Using & Editing Filters in Thunderbird](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/mozillaThunderbird/filtersInThunderbird.cwd)

If you can't delete mails based on a rule/filter, I suggest just filtering out all messages with 10+ contacts and **putting them in a separate folder, and then just mass-delete** everything in the  folder from time to time...

Comment: Please, read the question before answer.

Comment: as in past tense, @TheDisintegrator? *please* make it more clear that you want to do this for mails **already** in your inbox, and not messages still to come

Comment: You can use the built in message filters in both ways. but you cant create a filter like the one I'm describing, or at least, if you can. It's not evident.

Comment: Thunderbird allows you to run filters on both incoming and existing emails

Answer (score 0):

You can install [FiltaQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/) addon and write java script which does this.